# How to get a specific Sitecore rendering parameter from any razor file?

Tags: sitecore-client, razor, rendering-parameters

I have created a rendering parameter.

It is bound to a rendering called ProductRendering in its parameters template. This rendering is a controller rendering and points to a razor file called product.cshtml.

But I have another razor file called cart.cshtml and I need the above rendering parameter in this razor.

I am unable to get it in this razor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you are using to achieve this but it depends on the architecture of your project that how you pass the parameters. So I would suggest here two ways to do this.

1. Use `cart.cshtml` as a partial view and call this in your `product.cshtml` and pass the model in the partial view to get all the values you need.
2. Another way you can try is by creating this rendering as Compatible Rendering. A Compatible Rendering is simply a component that can be replaced with another component providing both use the same datasource type (or no datasource at all); e.g. use the same type of data.

You can follow this article to know about how to setup.

https://mattneil.co.uk/2017/01/17/compatible-renderings-in-sitecore/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @Sumit, if you follow #1 from his comment, on `productcontroller` you can get the rendering parameter

```
  string TitleCss = string.Empty, DescriptionCss = string.Empty;

        var rc = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull;
        if (rc != null)
        {
            var parms = rc.Rendering.Parameters;
            TitleCss = parms["TitleCss"];
            DescriptionCss = parms["DescriptionCss"];
        }
```

on `cart.cshtml` you can pass rendering parameters properties by viewmodel.

I hope it will help.